# Adding a number to certain elements of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array in numpy:

```
[1  2  3]
[4  5  6]
[7  8  9]
[10 11 12]
```

I would like to add 100 to all values that are greater than or equal to 3 and less than or equal to 8. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Please share the code of your tries so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a mask based on your criteria and then add 100 to each value.

```
arr = np.array([[1,  2,  3],
                [4,  5,  6],
                [7,  8, 9],
                [10, 11, 12]])
mask = (arr >= 3) & (arr <= 8)
arr[mask] += 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
>>> (x >= 3) * (x <= 8) * 100
array([[  0,   0, 100],
       [100, 100, 100],
       [100, 100,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0]])
```

and then add that to your array. Note that `(x >= 3) * (x <= 8)` contains boolean values that are cast to 0 or 1 once you multiply them with the integer 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
>>> a[np.where((8>=a) & (a>=3))]+=100
>>> a
array([[  1,   2, 103],
       [104, 105, 106],
       [107, 108,   9],
       [ 10,  11,  12]])
```

where `a` is :

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```